# using phpmailer mail sent but couldnt got form content

Tags: php, forms, email, post, phpmailer

I get email but i am not getting the content from the form though I have removed enctype tag from form Below is output i get in body of email

Name:
Organisation: 
Postal Address: 
City: 
Country: 
Email:
Telephone:
Comments:

what is wrong thing done by me can anyone help.

```
   <?php
     require("/home/public_html/phpMailerTesting/PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");
     $mail = new PHPMailer();

     $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP


     $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server

     $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication

     $mail->Username = "sendfromphpmailer@xxx.com";  // SMTP username

     $mail->Password = "12345"; // SMTP password
    enter code here


     $name=$_POST['name'];

     $email=$_POST['mail'];

     $message=$_POST['comment1'];

     $mail->From ="sendfromphpmailer@xxx.com" ;

     $mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];

     $mail->AddAddress("receivefromphpmailer@xxx.com");
                  // name is optional
     $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters

     $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

     $mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";

     $mail->Body    = "Name:$name

     Organisation: $organisation

     Postal Address: $PostalAddress

     City: $City

     Country: $Country

     Email:  $email

     Telephone:  $telephone

     Comments:  $comments";
    //$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
     echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     exit;
   }
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: Show your HTML form?

Comment: Can you please post the contact form code?

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST);` to see the Post fields, and show us the form HTML

Comment: You are using a very old and buggy version of PHPMailer. Get the latest from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/).

Comment: <form action="1.php" method="post">
Name: <sup><font color="red" font-style="bold">*</font></sup> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name"  required> <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" style="background:grey;  width:60px; height:30px">
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="reset" value="Reset"style="background:grey;  width:60px; height:30px">
</form>